# Ошибка кодировки в html/JSP Java Servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

Изучая Сервлеты решил попробовать создать JSP файл, куда будут передаваться параметры и выводить их в виде html страницы

*Однако возникает ошибка в кодировке русских букв, несмотря на то, что указал везде кодировку UTF-8. Ниже будут приведены коды и скриншоты:*
UPD: Добавил html-файл

**XML файл:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>WebApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>My</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.unlimit.MyServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>message</param-name>
            <param-value>Hello to Me</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>My</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyUrl</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSPfile</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/JSPfile.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSPfile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello-world-jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
  </error-page>
  
  <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/Info.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

**html файл**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action = "LoginServlet" method = "POST">
        Name : <input name = "username"/>
        <br><br>
        Password : <input name = "password" type="password">
        <br><br>
        <select name = "status">
            <option value = "Студент">Студент</option>
            <option value = "Профессор">Профессор</option>
            <option value = "Рабочий">Рабочий</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked />Male
        <br><br>
        Java Technoligies:
        <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "courses" value = "Java SE"> Java SE
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "courses" value = "Java EE"> Java EE
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "courses" value = "Java FX"> Java FX
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "courses" value = "Java Spring"> Java Spring
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "courses" value = "JDBC"> JDBC
        <br><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Сервлет LogIn:**

```
package ru.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import ru.unlimit.User;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String status = request.getParameter("status");
        System.out.println("status " + status);
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String[] courses = request.getParameterValues("courses");
        
        String path;
        if(username != null && password != null) {
            path = "/Info.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("username", username);
            request.setAttribute("password", password);
            request.setAttribute("status", status);
            request.setAttribute("gender", gender);
            request.setAttribute("courses", courses);
            System.out.println("Entered");
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Uncorrect LogIn");
            path = "/Login.html";
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

**и сам JSP файл:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Информация</h1>
    <p>username: ${username}</p>
    <p>user password: ${password}</p>
    <p>Status: ${status}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

И, соответственно, при воспроизведении JSP файла(точнее html) *некорректно отображаются русские символы*

> Прикладываю скриншоты
> [image: Ввод данных]

[image: Вывод данных]
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем ошибка
Спасибо

Comment: Та страница, с которой приходит значение status, не сохранена как utf-8 и значение (я так полагаю, это "студент"), как правило, и будет приходить таким.

Comment: Поменяй кодировку консоли. Причем тут jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед тем как получать данные

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

и т.д.
необходимо изменить кодировку запроса, а именно:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```